# Google Speed Leverage browser caching

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching, browser-cache

I got this error from Google Speed test:

The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the following resources:

```
http://localhost/english/favicon.ico (expiration not specified)
http://localhost/english/images/bg_center.png (expiration not specified)
http://localhost/english/images/bg_top.jpeg (expiration not specified)
http://localhost/english/images/footer_bg2.png (expiration not specified)
http://localhost/english/images/m_facebook.png (expiration not specified)
http://localhost/english/images/m_rss.png (expiration not specified)
http://localhost/english/images/top_bg.png (expiration not specified)
http://localhost/english/javascript/gram.js (expiration not specified)
http://localhost/english/javascript/top_start.js (expiration not specified)
http://localhost/english/jquery.js (expiration not specified)
http://localhost/english/style/gram.css (expiration not specified)
http://localhost/english/style/style.css (expiration not specified)
```

Should I do somthing in my htaccess file?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the static files don't have expires set. Read - http://www.absolutelytech.com/2010/08/02/howto-add-expire-headers-to-cache-static-files-using-htaccess/

You'll need to post the below code in your .htaccess

```
# Turn on the Expires engine
ExpiresActive On

# Expires after a month client accesses the file
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
ExpiresByType text/plain A2592000

# Good for one week
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript M604800
ExpiresByType text/css M604800
ExpiresByType text/html M604800
```

Comment: How to do it with web.config file? (in Windows), can this be done in shared hosting?

Comment: I don't have much idea about windows systems. If it is a directory specific configuration which the hosting provider hasn't restricted, it should work in shared hosting environment as well.

Answer (score 0):

PageSpeed: Leverage browser caching
Every time a browser loads a webpage it has to download all the web files to properly display the page. This includes all the HTML, CSS, javascript and images.

To enable browser caching you need to edit your HTTP headers to set expiry dates on certain types of files.

Find your .htaccess file in the root of your domain, this file is a hidden file but should show up in FTP clients like FileZilla or CORE. You can edit the htaccess file with notepad or any form of basic text editor.

```html
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```